# Capitalization of xml Declarations

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

Just having some problems with XML Capitalization. I am required to produce the following xml namespace using a XSLT File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

However, after being processed by my XSLT Engine the declarations changes the capitalization of ISO to iso.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
```

My Question were:

```
  1). Is/Are there any significant difference between these two declarations?
  2). Is is possible to retain the capitalization of ISO?
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921533/is-the-xml-declaration-tag-case-sensitive

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your terminology isn't quite right - you are asking not about the **XML Namespace** but about the **XML declaration** and more specifically about the encoding attribute within the XML declaration. The namespaces are a different thing http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces. I'd suggest you edit that but will leave it to your discretion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of 1) of your question has already been answered by the question referenced in Tangelo's comment, I will just address part 2).

You **should** be able use the  element to control the encoding via the 'encoding' attribute. The value of the attribute **should** be emitted exactly as you specify its case in the style-sheet.

Example:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" />
```

However, having said that, please note this extract from the XSLT 1.0 spec ...

> - encoding: specifies the preferred character encoding that the XSLT
>     processor should use to encode sequences of characters as sequences of
>     bytes; the value of the attribute should be treated
>     case-insensitively; the value must contain only characters in the
>     range #x21 to #x7E (i.e. printable ASCII characters); the value should
>     either be a charset registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers
>     Authority [IANA], [RFC2278] or start with X-

That means there is no absolute guaranteed way to control the case genererically across all XSLT processors, so now the question comes down to what is your XSLT processor? The answer will be vendor specific.