# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/device_filter')

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

Android has me completely at a loss here. Android noob and I think it shows:

I get the following error in the Android Manifest file :

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/device_filter').

I have retyped both the manifest file and the xml/device_file manually with no copying and pasting. Looked at both files with a hex editor to see if there were any lurking odd characters but zero , nothing. I have tried renaming both files, moving them to other folders and back again and Cleaned Project after every attempt. R is not generating either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.cccu.stage2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.cccu.stage2.FindDevice"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.cccu.stage2.Stage2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the device_filter.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<usb-accessory manuafacturer="FTDI" model="FTDIUARTDemo" version="1.0" />
<usb-accessory manufacturer="FTDI" model="Android Accessory FT312D" version="1.0" />
<usb-device manufacturer="FTDI" vendor-id="1027" version="1.0" />
</resources>
```

Comment: Did you placed your device_filter.xml file in res/xml folder?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue. Copied example from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html. Just found another example that is almost identical, but works. The only difference I could find was that in the accessory_filter.xml file, the encoding was given as "utf-8", whereas "UTF-8" works See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921533/is-the-xml-declaration-tag-case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is ancient, but I found it due to having the same issue when developing on Xamarin. In my case, the Build Action was not properly set on device_filter.xml

1. Select **device_filter.xml** in the Solution Explorer
2. In the file's **Properties** pane, set **Build Action** to **AndroidResource**

I checked Android Studio whether there is a similar property but have not found one. AS is not my primary tool, however. I have not checked past versions or Eclipse.